# Get position of EpoxyModel<*> on the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, epoxy

I'm trying to get the position of the EpoxyModel on my screen so that I can add an overlay on that spot. In my fragment I'm not sure I have a way to access the view in the viewHolder to do `view.getLocationOnScreen(location)`

Is this possible in Epoxy?